# Read a file line by line and put the data in a struct array in c

Tags: c, struct, while-loop, c-strings

I'm trying to read a text file in C. And I want to put the info in a struct.

I think I'm reading the file correctly but when I have to print the info, all the data is filled by the last line of the text.

Do you know why?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXCHAR 1000

int main() {
    
    struct lumi {
        char *domini;
        char *disponible;
    };
    
    struct lumi registre[256];
    int i = 0;
    
    FILE *fp;
    char str[MAXCHAR];
    char* filename = "fitxer.txt";
 
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL){
        registre[i].domini = str;
        registre[i].disponible = "offline";
        i = i+1;
    }
    printf("%s", registre[0].domini);
    printf("%s", registre[1].domini);
    printf("%s", registre[2].domini);
    printf("%s", registre[3].domini);


    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The .txt I tried is

```
Hi
My
Name
Is
```

Comment: All what you are doing is pointer assignment. You need to copy the contents of the string.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Although you are right he should be copying instead of just assigning the pointer. It's not directly related to his problem since he has 256 structures each with its own pointer assignment. So long as the data stays in memory the pointers should be valid. The issue is actually he's reading the entire file in one buffer, not splitting up the buffer into lines.

Comment: @Nina reread his problem statement `I think I'm reading the file correctly but when i have to print the info, all the data is fill by the last line of the text`.

Comment: From what I can see of that code, he's reading the entire file into a buffer just once with fgets. Then not seperating the buffer through a line delimeter...

Comment: @Nina Also `fgets` will read the online per read, if `\n` is detected earlier then the number of bytes requested it will stop the reading.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Ah my mistake then. Then yes you are right, the issue is that he is assigning the pointers rather than copying the data. Because the data is being overwritten with every iteration.

Comment: `if(fp==NULL) {perror(filename); ...}`  Error messages should be informative and written to stderr.